# trigger a HTML button when you press Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, tampermonkey

I am trying to make a button key "trigger" on a specific page using tampermonkey. Instead of using mouse click every time to click Button called "continue".

So when I click keyboard button "ENTER" this hover button should be automatically clicked, theres any ready to use code while I can just put this HTML code.
Thanks.

```
<button id="simplicityPayment-START" type="submit" autocomplete="off" class="nf-btn nf-btn-primary nf-btn-solid nf-btn-oversize" data-uia="action-submit-payment">START MEMBERSHIP</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

### USING JQUERY

You can use easy jQuery to achieve it.
Just add a cdn given below in your main HTML page

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And just open a script tags and copy paste this code.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){

var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
    $("#simplicityPayment-START").click();
}});
```

### USING PURE JAVASCRIPT (NO EXTERNAL LIBRARY)

**EDIT 1:** As don't own the website & using tampermonkey. Okay so there is another way to achieve this, that is Pure JAVASCRIPT. it requires no CDN.
just Add this JAVASCRIPT.

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
     var button = document.getElementById("simplicityPayment-START");
     button.click();
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: I do not own that page. I am just using a tampermonkey to make changes through it and it accepts just jquery lines. code is added well but how could I give cdn to that HTML page, and thanks alot <3

Comment: I just edited my own comment with the correct answer for you. (Pure Javascript).But I let the jquery solution for other people to use it.

Comment: That's not how you use jQuery in a Tampermonkey script, so the first answer is wrong. But the "Pure JavaScript" part of the answer is correct.

Comment: @BrockAdams as OP hasn't included `in tempermonkey` so even any user find this they need to `trigger a HTML button when you press Enter`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `autofocus` attribute to button, but I'm not sure if this will work with tampermonkey. Because I think it need to be in html when page load.

You can also use this:

```
 document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').focus();
```

it will give focus to button and you will be able to submit the form with space or enter. But this if you click outside of the button you will not be able to press enter to submit the form. If you need to do some action then you can add this focus after user do something. You can also add focus when you click on document.

```
var button = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
   button.focus();
});
```